# What's wrong with my print_random_sprites function?

Tags: c, random, teensy

I'm writing some code in C that randomly displays sprites on an LCD screen on a microprocessor. Currently when I run this code it produces 8 lines running from the top to bottom. So it's printing something in random order but not the sprite. Why is this? Could anyone help me? (NOTE: rand is seeded in a separate function which works fine, the problem is just within this code.)

```
void zombies() {

    Sprite zombie_sprite;
    Sprite * zombie_sprite_pointer = &zombie_sprite;
    byte zombie_bitmap [] = {
    BYTE( 11100000 ),
    BYTE( 01000000 ),
    BYTE( 11100000 )
};

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Sprite * zombie_sprites = &zombie_sprites[i];
        init_sprite(zombie_sprites, rand()%76, rand()%42, 3, 3, zombie_bitmap);
        }
    create_zombies();       
}

void create_zombies(Sprite * zombie_sprites) {
    while(1) {
    clear();
    draw_sprite( &zombie_sprites );
    refresh();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have called `create_zombies()` without supplying an argument.

Comment: This line `Sprite * zombie_sprites = &zombie_sprites[i];` generates a compiler warning. Rightly so: it is self-referencing.

Comment: The random lines look different now but it's still not displaying the sprites

Comment: Will it display **one** sprite that is stationary? A moving sprite, even if it works properly, may not look like you expect it to.

Comment: No it's just supposed to print a sprite randomly 8 times, so all up there should be 8 sprites on the screen in random positions,

Comment: I am asking if you can do the simple case before you try the complicated case. Can you make **one** sprite in a fixed position? If you can't do that, you won't be able to print 8 sprites in random positions, and you won't know why.

Comment: Good point, will try that

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `Sprite zombie_sprite` is only one object.  Make this an array of objects and you can start looking at other problems.  Next there is a fair bit of confusion over pointers to the `Sprite` objects.  To simplify things a bit we can tweak the variables in the `zombies` function, along with some 'tidying up' for best practices.

```
// Start by using a compile-time constant to define the number of zombies.
// This could be changed to a vriable in the, once the simple case is working.
#define NUMBER_OF_ZOMBIES 8

void zombies()
{
    // Eight zombies are required, so define an array of eight sprites.
    Sprite zombie_sprites[NUMBER_OF_ZOMBIES];
    byte zombie_bitmap [] = 
    {
        BYTE( 11100000 ),
        BYTE( 01000000 ),
        BYTE( 11100000 )
    };

// Continued below...
```

This makes the rest of the function to initialise the sprites easier.  This time, it is possible to get the pointer to the `i`th element in the array.  Also, you will see that the `create_zombies` function requires an argument: the address of a `Sprite` object, so pass it the address of the first sprite in the same array that has just been initialised.

Again, with a bit of housekeeping, the rest of the function would look like this:

```
    // ...continued from above

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ZOMBIES; i++)
    {
        // Initialise the ith sprite using the address of its element
        // in the zombie_sprites array.
        init_sprite(&zombie_sprites[i], rand()%76, rand()%42,
                    3, 3, zombie_bitmap);
    }

    // Animate the zombies in the array.
    create_zombies(&zombie_sprites[0]);       
}
```

Finally, the `create_zombies` function itself needs a minor change to loop through all of the sprites in the array passed as its parameter.  Also, being of type `void` it does not have a return statement.

```
void create_zombies(Sprite * zombie_sprites)
{
    while(1)
    {
        clear();

        // loop round drawing all of the sprites.
        for(int zombie_index = 0; zombie_index < NUMBER_OF_ZOMBIES; zombie_index++)
        {
            draw_sprite( &zombie_sprites[zombie_index] );
        }

        refresh();
    }
}
```

Future enhancements might include:

- Changing NUMBER_OF_ZOMBIES to be a variable.
- Replacing the static array with a dynamically allocated array using `malloc` and `free`.
- Replacing the array with a more complex abstract data type such as a list or doubly linked list, so that zombies can be added or removed at run-time.
- Renaming the functions and restructuring where each gets called.